# iOS Core Data - Design Pattern for Passing Context to Detail Views

Tags: iphone, core-data, ios

I'm a little stumped with an issue that I think goes back to my design.

I'm constructing a TableViewController based on a mainly static set of rows (4) - using that as a basis for a UITableView.  Each row will kick off varying different views (detail, and UITableViews)...  In my managed object context for the top view I can easily nav to the associated detail view because it's in context (nickname).. I initially thought about simply having unrelated tables and a series of buttons that would fire off the views... But I ditched that idea.  My main current issue is knowing how to switch MOC or to different fetchedresults controllers (which are by the way defined in each .m to fetch from different tables.

At the moment, I've got a switch inside of TableViewControler.m.. This snipit works:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSInteger switchval = indexPath.row;

    switch (switchval) {
     case 0: // Nickname 
     {
       //This version brings up a detailed view controller - 
      NickNameDetail *controller = [[NickNameDetail alloc] initWithNibName:@"NickNameDetail" bundle:nil];
      controller.fetchedResultsController = self.fetchedResultsController;
      controller.managedObjectContext = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
      break;  
     }
     case 1:  
     {      
      //NextTableViewContoller *.... (etc)... here here
    ...
```

However, I can't figure out how to switch to a different context and get different rows.

```
meTableViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
nickNameDetail.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
nextTableViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

Anyone run into a scenario like this before?  Sorry, can't get the code formatter to behave.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases it may be good/opportune to pass to the new view controller pushed on the navigation stack the MOC of your current view controller. However, you usually want to pass a newly created MOC. Do this as follows:

in your app delegate add the following method

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext*)createNewManagedObjectContext
{

    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init]; 
    [moc setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[self persistentStoreCoordinator]]; 
    return [moc autorelease];
}
```

in your view controller pass the MOC as follows

```
myAppDelegate *mainDelegate = (myAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *mainMOC = [mainDelegate createNewManagedObjectContext]; 
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(contextDidSave:) 
                                                         name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                                       object:mainMOC];

newViewController.managedObjectContext = mainMOC;
```

and then handle the notification as needed, here is an example

```
- (void)contextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification
{

    [managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

You also need to define and use a different NSFetchedResultsController for each of your view controllers. This is because the data you want to fetch and display are, of course, different for each view controller (different entity, predicate etc). Simply define them in each implementation file. Here is an example:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return fetchedResultsController;
    }

    /*
     Set up the fetched results controller.
     */

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Context" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    if(self.project){
        // get the contexts for the project
        NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"projectName == %@", self.project.name];
        [request setPredicate:predicate];
    }

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];


    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [request release];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];

    return fetchedResultsController;
}
```

and then use the fetchedResultsController as needed. For instance, put this in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
    NSError *error;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        // Handle error
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        exit(-1);  // Fail
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  I will give this a try.  It does make sense on various levels.  Sorry for my late reply, email notification in my prefs didn't seem to work...

Comment: Well, if you like the answer, consider voting it ;-)

Comment: Hi unforgiven, This approach actually works nicely.  I just wired it up and only received 2 warnings: (1) Local declaration of 'mainDelegate' hides instance variable
(2) 'myAppDeligate' may not respond to '-createNewManagedObjectContext'.   I'll dig into that analysis, but I must say, I'm impressed!

Comment: I am interested in understanding this piece relative to the whole projects predicates.  I don't have any predicates stated prior to this, but will no doubt after I get it.  if(self.project){
        // get the contexts for the project
        NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"projectName == %@", self.project.name];
        [request setPredicate:predicate];
    }           ....  You defeintely get my vote as answered!  A very much appreciated thank you! :)

Comment: To solve the warnings: 1) change mainDelegate to something different (e.g. myDelegate) because you already have a variable named mainDelegate; 2) add in the header file for your app delegate the method - (NSManagedObjectContext*)createNewManagedObjectContext;

Comment: About predicates: a predicate is the way you tell to Core Data what data you want to fetch; in my example, the predicate allows fetching from the Context entity only those contexts whose associated project's name is the one I am specifying. You may want to read the associated documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001798-SW1

Comment: One last question, and I might have this figured out before you have a chance to reply.  I'm now drilling down to a detail view, and coming up with a view with empty fields... I have other detailed views that work and I know how to wire up via IB.  I think I'm not passing this new MOC properly...Appreciate what you may have insights on in this journey.. :)

Comment: Simply create a new MOC and pass it as already shown in the example snipped I have posted if you need to add new objects in the detail view. Otherwise, if you simply need to show detail items, then you may pass the current MOC associated to the master view controller to the new view controller you are pushing on the stack. If you do not get back correct information, then it is probably not correct the way you fetch the data you want to show (wrong predicate or something else).

Comment: Hi, I'm still having issues with the detail view.  I was able to get it force pushed w/data, but once in the instantiated view, there's no moc, so I can't do any trapping for anything like Save, Add.. Code in next comment..I am missing something for sure...

Comment: - (void)showFavorite:(Favorites *)favorite animated:(BOOL)animated {
 FavoritesDetail *favoriteController = [[FavoritesDetail alloc] initWithNibName:@"FavoritesDetail" bundle:nil];
 (void)favoriteController.view; 
 favoriteController.favoriteField.text = favorite.fav_name;
 favoriteController.favCategory.text = favorite.fav_category; 
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:favoriteController animated:animated];
 [favoriteController release];       
} // This fails in the detail's viewDidload:  if (self.managedObjectContext != nil)

Comment: Whatever time you may have will be appreciated :)

Comment: Indeed you are NOT passing the MOC.Do something like the following BEFORE pushing favoriteController on the stack.

Comment: myAppDelegate *mainDelegate = (myAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *mainMOC = [mainDelegate createNewManagedObjectContext]; 
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(contextDidSave:) 
                                                         name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                                       object:mainMOC];

pushViewController:favoriteController.managedObjectContext = mainMOC;

Comment: Making it a bit further along.  Having issues on Saving the MOC now. I think it's related to the multiple NSNotificationCenter calls. But not sure.  I wish these small comment boxes weren't so limiting format wise... anyway I dropped in NSLogs at key points, and found that the new MOC originally created is different than the one From the FavoritesTableView... Basically using the same code all the way down.  Here's the Console output:

Comment: MyApp[1173:207] 1) MeTableViewController Click on Favorites: MOC Created: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x613eb50>
MyApp[1173:207] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0015s for 7 rows
MyApp[1173:207] 2) Initialize favMoc in Show Favorite: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x6454250>
MyApp[1173:207] 3) In the Favs Detail view Did Load MOC: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x6454250>
MyApp[1173:207] 4) Inside if (self.managedObjectContext != nil): <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x6454250>

Comment: MyApp[1173:207] 5) In the Save MOC managedObjectContext: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x6454250>
MyApp[1173:207] 6) checking self.managedObjectContext validity <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x6454250>
MyApp[1173:207] -[FavoritesViewController contextDidSave:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x613e9f0

Comment: Wonder if it would be easier to send the project over to you (if it's appropriate)?  You've already spend a bunch of time helping me, and I appreciate it greatly.

Comment: [FavoritesViewController contextDidSave:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x613e9f0  This basically means that you need to add the method declaration in the header file FavoritesViewController.h, and the actual implementation in FavoritesViewController.m The code for the implementation is already available in the original answer.

Comment: Thanks!   I need to figure out how to provide you more ratings/credit.    MOC is now intact at the right time.

Comment: -1 Sorry to downcheck but there is no reason to create a new managed object context just because you are pushing a new controller. The context manages the interface with the persistent store and it doesn't care how many UI elements use the same context. In the vast majority of cases, you only need a second context when you have concurrent data being written to the persistent store e.g. downloading data in a background thread while the user is accessing the data in the foreground.

Comment: I thought that was the case. I believe my approach needs to be re-thought regardless.  My tab bar app starts with 4 rows in a table view, which are basically categories.  Once clicked, there will be either a detail view for that 1 item, or on the 2nd row, launching a UITableViewController - a root, then a drill down to detail.  Thinking I need to set the structure up with p-lists, and then store needed values in coredata.Similar to that Starbucks app on the MyStarbucks section (like an app prefs). Another recommended looking at coredatalibary: http://code.google.com/p/coredatalibrary/. Hmmm

Comment: TechZen: yes, I usually do things concurrently in different threads, but, besides this, there is another reason for creating a new MOC: if you discard a newly created object, then you simply discard the MOC and you are done. Otherwise, you have to delete the object and save the context. You have to save the objects you create in both cases, but if you instead want to cancel an object this approach is, in my opinion, better and faster.

Comment: Well, this was an adventure that actually didn't work out.  I'm looking into re-modeling the model.  It's been a challenge finding answers on what I feel is a simple pattern.  Just looking to have a Top level tableview (4 static rows or objects) that navigate to separate detail or tableviews - with core data.  Like the iPhone Prefreences app.   I've hunted everywhere - mums the word.